# I have to delete the particular Cookie if the url has specific term like /abc-def/ using jQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have to delete the particular Cookie if the url has specific term like /abc-def/ using jQuery.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Please show us the code that isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in plain javascript as well:

```
var deleteCookie = function(name,urlValue) {
 if(window.location.href.indexOf(urlValue) > -1{
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
 }
};
```

and then just call the `deleteCookie("test", "/abc-def/");`

Answer (score 0):

To remove a cookie via jQuery use `$.removeCookie('cookie_name', { path: '/' });`

In your case try:

```
$.removeCookie('cookie_name', { path: '/abc-def/' });
```